# Alternative of simple UNION in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Is it possible to write below query as a single query without Union as we fetch records from same table?

```
Select Primary_Employee From Employee e
UNION
Select Secondary_Employee From Employee e
```

Comment: Not if you want one column only.

Comment: ya i am looking for one column

Comment: Then do UNION, or perhaps UNION ALL - if you don't mind duplicates.

Comment: Not possible if you are looking for the result in one column

Comment: I dont want duplicates thats the reason i used Union.

Comment: It would help if you could explain why the simple, straightforward `UNION` is for some reason not the right solution for you.

Comment: damien, i am a beginner and exploring options.

Answer (score 1):

`VALUES` table value cosntructor and `CROSS APPLY` is an option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.Employee
FROM Employee e
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Primary_Employee), (Secondary_Employee)) v(Employee)
```

Comment: @Amudha . . . I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate this behavior with a cross join and apply `distinct` on the result (since `union`, unlike `union all` returns distinct values), but to be completely honest, it's considerably less elegant than using `union`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(primary_employee, secondary_employee)
FROM   (SELECT primary_employee AS primary_employee, NULL AS secondary_employee
        FROM   employee
        CROSS JOIN
        SELECT NULL, secondary_employee
        FROM   employee) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this specific case where it is reading from single table, you could use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.col
FROM employee
UNPIVOT (col FOR Employee IN (Primary_Employee, Secondary_Employee)) AS u;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a06c5a8b9e6862e0722ca83d4e67b8a9)**